Select from a job list for SQL Server Agent jobs
We have a SQL Server table dbo.JobList that is regularly filled with new entries. These represent tasks for multiple agent jobs that are executing SSIS packages.
First step of the SSIS package is to select from the JobList. The agent jobs are scheduled to run every 15 minutes.
As of now the different agent jobs are selecting by the JobName, so we're sure each entry is only picked up once at the same time.
SELECT TOP (10)   
    ID,   
    JobName,  
    JobDate,  
    Processed  
FROM 
    dbo.JobList  
WHERE 
    LEFT(JobName, 2) = 'PA' AND Processed = 0 

Here 'PA' is configured as a parameter for the SSIS package in the agent job and there are around 30 + agent jobs.
After processing the job, the column Processed is updated from 0 to 1, so we're again making sure it is not picked up again.
Unfortunately, the job names (first 2 letters) are not equally distributed. This leads to the fact that some jobs have finished processing all jobs of a day within an hour, whilst others barely manage to process all jobs within a day. E.g., there are 12 entries for 'PA' in JobList but 200 for 'CB'.
I'm looking for a way to make the selection of jobs independent from JobName, so all agent jobs are loaded with the same amount of entries and at the same time make sure each job is only picked up by once by an agent job.
So, I need to make sure that multiple SELECT TOP (10) statements (or something else) do not pick up the same entries from JobList.
Are there any recommendations or buzz words that I can use to further investigate?

This is a very SQL Server specific problem, so I removed the general ANSI/ISO SQL tag.

Do multiple packages start at the same time? Or, how do you prevent a job run taking same jobs in current code? A suggestion would be to add a flag called "InProcess" which is immediately set after SSIS job starts and fetched it's jobs. Or make Processed a tri-state column which goes from: 0 (Ready) => 1 (In process) => 2 (Done). Then you can just take TOP 10 Jobs ordered by whatever distribution you're interested in

Yeah, use a proper queue rather than using static logic.

They can start at the same time. But selecting by the first 2 letters of the name prevents selecting the same jobs again. There is only one job selecting a name staring with e.g. 'PA'

I thought about the "in progress" flag, then this needs to be part of the select, like InProgress = 0 or something. But what happens when a job / package fails? Then I'd need to include it again somehow, meaning to select InProgress = 1

Yes, that's the classic problem. You need some sort of clean up logic, either manually or automatically. You can either link certain rows against your job id and then check if it's still running, or have some special step unlocking the rows on failure. There's no fool proof way i think.

@siggemannen Yes, classic is the right word ;-) Maybe I'll think about this idea again, Thanks!

@DaleK What do you consider to be a proper queue, like said, I'm looking for ideas.

You can research how a queue works, simply you have a list of entries stored somehow, and a mechanism for a process to remove an entry (or entries) from the queue and flag it as in progress so no other process attempts to handle it. All the while handling concurrency i.e. avoiding two processes taking the same item off the queue at the same time.

Are the "jobs" you're trying to run actual SQL Agent Jobs or Job Steps? Or is it more "a collection of code that does a task"? If the "jobs" are defined as actual job steps of some freestanding Agent Job, then you can compare the date the "job" was added to the queue versus the last time the job step was run
